# Program resulting in an infinite loop, what is the flow of execution?

Tags: java

```
P s v m(Str args)
{
  go:
    for(;;){
          fact:
              for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
                {
                   s.o.p(i);
                 }
      }
}
```

Comment: where is the exit condition for the 1st `for` Loop

Answer (score 2):

A `go` loop results in an infinite loop when no conditions are provided to control the loop.

You can otherwise add `break` statements without modifying current code as below:

```
go: for (;;) {

    fact: for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);

        if (i == 2) // put some matching condition to break go: for infinite loop
            break go;
    }

    if (true) // put some matching condition to break go: for infinite loop
        break;

}
```

Comment: manishankar I just get - 1212121212121212121212...You may be observing such thing because you are not able to capture output correctly.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh but what is the use of go and fact instead of using go and fact we can use anything but we get same output.. I am asking what is use of go: and fact:

Comment: These are labels...a plain text - you can replace with any name you want. Purpose - A label provides a statement with an identifier that lets you refer to it elsewhere in your program.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        go: for(;;){
            fact: for(int i=1;i<3;i++) {
                   System.out.println(i); 
            } 
        }
    }
```

And it is definitely infinite loop `for(;;)`. This loop has no initialization, no condition and no increment/decrement and so it will run forever.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

An infinite loop can be created as follows:

```
// infinite loop

for ( ; ; ) {

    // your code goes here
}
```

Infinite loop because there is no condition to stop the loop.

For loop Syntax

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update)
{
   //Statements
}
```

> the Boolean expression is evaluated. If it is true, the body of the
>   loop is executed. If it is false, the body of the loop does not
>   execute and flow of control jumps to the next statement past the for
>   loop.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop  is because of this

```
for ( ; ; ) {
}
```

You need to provide a condition in your for loop to stop it.

From the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

> ```
> for (initialization; termination;
>      increment) {
>     statement(s)
> }
> ```
>
> When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>
> - The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed    once, as the loop begins.
> - When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop    terminates.
> - The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the    loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to
>     increment or    decrement a value.